# Disable auto-pairing of characters in Textmate 2?

Tags: textmate2

TextMate 1 had a preference called "Auto-pair characters (quotes etc.)" that would allow you to enable or disable the auto pairing functionality.

Is it possible to disable this feature in TextMate 2?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can disable it for a given bundle as explained in [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/textmate/textmate/issues/609).
Basically you have to edit an option file of the bundle and add `smartTypingPairs = ( );` near the end of the file.

I don't know if this can be generalized using the `.tm_properties` files but you are welcome to try (and report your results).

There is also a user defaults key for this:

```
defaults write com.macromates.TextMate disableTypingPairs -bool YES
```

Answer (score 11):

Automatic "Typing Pairs" is a [TextMate 2 Hidden Setting](https://github.com/textmate/textmate/wiki/Hidden-Settings#disabling-auto-paired-characters)

> When you type an opening brace, parenthesis, quote character, or similar, TextMate will insert the closing character.

**Disable via Terminal:**

```
defaults write com.macromates.TextMate disableTypingPairs YES
```

Answer (score 0):

A follow-up for Ruby coders. After disabling auto-pairing, you'll still find that typing `#` inside a double-quoted (`"..."`) string expands to `#{}`. If you want to disable this:

- "Bundles" menu -> "Edit Bundles..."
- Select "Ruby" in the left column
- Select "Other Actions" in the next column
- Select "Embedded Code - #{...}" in the third column
- Turn off the "Enable this item" checkbox in the drawer
- Type Cmd+S to save the updated bundle

Now you can type `"#` without any auto-expansion/pairing. If you like typing `#` and having the first `{` appear but don't want the closing `}` added, then instead of disabling the item, just edit in the bottom pane to remove the trailing `}`:

```
#{${1:$TM_SELECTED_TEXT}
```

If you like selecting text within strings and typing `#` to have it enclosed in `#{...}` though, the above changed will make it quite awkward, so beware.